# How do I test a manual check in check_mk / Nagios

Tags: nagios

My organization is using Nagios with the [check_mk](http://mathias-kettner.de/index.html) plugin to monitor our nodes. My question is: is it possible run a [manual check](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_manualchecks.html) from the command line? It is important, process-wise, to be able to test a configuration change before deploying it.

For example, I've prepared a configuration change which uses the [ps.perf](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_check_ps.perf.html) check type to check the number of httpd processes on our web servers. The check looks like this:

```
checks = [
  ( ["web"], ALL_HOSTS, "ps.perf", "Number of httpd processes", ( "/usr/sbin/httpd", 1, 2, 80, 100 ) )
]
```

I would like to test this configuration change before committing and deploying it.

Is it possible to run this check via the command line, without first adding it to `main.mk`? I'm envisioning something like:

```
useful_program -H my.web.node -c ps.perf -A /usr/sbin/httpd,1,2,80,100
```

I don't see any way to do something like this in the check_mk documentation, but am hoping there is a way to achieve something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

that is easy to check.

Just make your config changes and then run:
cmk -nv HOSTNAME.

That (-n) will try run everything and return (-v) the output.

So can see the same results like later in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

List the check

```
$check_mk -L | grep ps.perf
```

if it listing ps.perf then run following command,

```
$check_mk --checks=ps.perf -I Hostname
```

Comment: That doesn't quite do what I'm asking. I'm asking for a way to run a specific check with parameters.